# Git: search for all commits referring a particular file in any ways at once?

Tags: git, git-log

Is it possible to run these 3 actions at once with the `OR` semantics, and browse through the output with the standard pager (`less`?)

1. `git log '**/foo.c'` (look for commits updating `foo.c` somewhere in the repo)
2. `git log -G foo.c` (look for commits whose diff contain a string `foo.c`)
3. `git log --grep foo.c` (look for commits whose comments mention a string `foo.c`)

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not "one" command which would output a combined result, but you can chain them in:

- a bash session:

  ```
  git log '**/foo.c'; git log -G foo.c; git log --grep foo.c
  ```
- a CMD Windows session

  ```
  git log "**/foo.c"&& git log -G foo.c&& git log --grep foo.c
  ```

If, by "OR" semantic, you need to see only one commit, I would recommend adding `--oneline` to your logs, and redirect the result to a file.
You can then `sort|uniq` that file, to get common commits *one* time.

```
(git log '**/foo.c'; git log -G foo.c; git log --grep foo.c)>/tmp/f; cat /tmp/f|sort|uniq
```